# Latex error in my compilation

Tags: errors, compiling

What's wrong with my code test ? I do this to

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\frenchbsetup{StandardLists=true}
%\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{ mathrsfs}
 \usepackage{fancyhdr}
 \pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{tr}{rgb}{0.22,.26,.64}
 \definecolor{bl}{RGB}{022,119,184}
  \definecolor{or}{RGB}{254,89,0}
  \definecolor{v1}{RGB}{224,237,224}
%\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[frenchstyle]{kpfonts}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{ifsym}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{vmargin}
\usepackage{setspace}
 \doublespacing
\parindent= 0 cm
\setmarginsrb{1cm}{2 cm}{2 cm}{1 cm}{1 cm}{0 cm}{0 cm}{0.5 cm}

\begin{document}%********************************************************************************************************
\begin{center}
\textsc{\Large Questionnaire}
\end{center}
\vspace{2 cm}
\fcolorbox{white}{v1}{\begin{minipage}{17 cm}
\textsc{L'âge}                        %l'âge_________________________________________________________________________
\end{minipage}}
{\color{gray!15}\rule[0.6 cm]{17.2 cm}{0.03 cm}}
1. Quel est votre âge? \hspace{10 cm}  \fbox{\hspace{3 cm}{\color{white}on}}
{\color{gray!15}\rule[-0.6 cm]{17.2 cm}{0.03 cm}}
\fcolorbox{white}{v1}{\begin{minipage}{17 cm}
\textsc{Sexe}           %________________________________________________________________________________________
\end{minipage}}
{\color{gray!15}\rule[0.6 cm]{17.2 cm}{0.03 cm}}
2. Vous êtes : Homme (1) ; Femme (2 ) ;
 $\textbigcircle \,$  1.1\hspace{1 cm} $\textbigcircle \,$ 2.2  

 {\color{gray!15}\rule[-0.6 cm]{17.2 cm}{0.03 cm}}
\fcolorbox{white}{v1}{\begin{minipage}{17 cm}
\textsc{La taille}          %_______________________________________________________________________________________
\end{minipage}}
{\color{gray!15}\rule[0.6 cm]{17.2 cm}{0.03 cm}}
3. Quelle est votre taille ( en $cm$ )? \hspace{8 cm}  \fbox{\hspace{3 cm}{\color{white}on}}
 {\color{gray!15}\rule[-0.6 cm]{17.2 cm}{0.03 cm}}
\fcolorbox{white}{v1}{\begin{minipage}{17 cm}
\textsc{Bac}    %_______________________________________________________________________________________________
\end{minipage}}
{\color{gray!15}\rule[0.6 cm]{18.5 cm}{0.03 cm}}

 \end{document}
```

Comment: Unrelated, but if you want to design questionnaires, you might insterested in the `exam` class.

Comment: Could you paste the error you've got? Perhaps you didn't install a specific package?

Comment: ! LaTeX Error: Command `\leftmoon' already defined.See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... ...athSymbol{\leftmoon} {0}{mathb}{"4B}

Comment: ! LaTeX Error: Command `\rightmoon' already defined.See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... ...athSymbol{\rightmoon} {0}{mathb}{"4C}

Comment: Please be more specific; see http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/bugs.html . And please condense your code to make it an MWE.

Comment: both `wasysym.sty` and `mathabx.sty` (via `mathabx.dcl`) define `\leftmoon`.  your preamble looks as if you've grabbed at all the symbol packages you can think of: if so, you need to find whether you can avoid loading either.  if you do need both, add the command `\let\leftmoon\relax` after loading `wasysym.sty` -- this ‘undefines’ the command, ready for `mathabx` to define it again.

Answer (score 3):

You weren't specific as to what *you* think is wrong with your example, but I'll assume it's the fact that several lines start far to the right -- basically, outside the text block.

A straightforward way to fix this is to provide blank lines between certain lines of code, because all-blank lines are interpreted by TeX as paragraph breaks.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\frenchbsetup{StandardLists=true}
%\usepackage{textcomp} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{ mathrsfs}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
  \definecolor{tr}{rgb}{0.22,.26,.64}
  \definecolor{bl}{RGB}{022,119,184}
  \definecolor{or}{RGB}{254,89,0}
  \definecolor{v1}{RGB}{224,237,224}
%\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[frenchstyle]{kpfonts}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{ifsym}
%\usepackage{mathabx} %% commented out to avoid duplication of "\leftmoon"
\usepackage{vmargin}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
\parindent= 0 cm
\setmarginsrb{1cm}{2 cm}{2 cm}{1 cm}{1 cm}{0 cm}{0 cm}{0.5 cm}

\begin{document}
\vspace*{0.5cm}

\begin{center}
\textsc{\Large Questionnaire}
\end{center}


{\color{gray!15}\rule[-0.6 cm]{17.2 cm}{0.03 cm}}

\fcolorbox{white}{v1}{\begin{minipage}{17 cm}
\textsc{L'âge}\end{minipage}}

{\color{gray!15}\rule[0.6 cm]{17.2 cm}{0.03 cm}}

1. Quel est votre âge? \hspace{10 cm}  
\fbox{\hspace{3 cm}{\color{white}on}}

{\color{gray!15}\rule[-0.6 cm]{17.2 cm}{0.03 cm}}

\fcolorbox{white}{v1}{\begin{minipage}{17 cm}
\textsc{Sexe}\end{minipage}}

{\color{gray!15}\rule[0.6 cm]{17.2 cm}{0.03 cm}}

2. Vous êtes : Homme (1) ; Femme (2 ) ;
 $\textbigcircle \,$  1.1\hspace{1 cm} $\textbigcircle \,$ 2.2  

{\color{gray!15}\rule[-0.6 cm]{17.2 cm}{0.03 cm}}

\fcolorbox{white}{v1}{\begin{minipage}{17 cm}
\textsc{La taille}\end{minipage}}

{\color{gray!15}\rule[0.6 cm]{17.2 cm}{0.03 cm}}

3. Quelle est votre taille ( en \emph{cm} )? \hspace{8 cm}  \fbox{\hspace{3 cm}{\color{white}on}}

{\color{gray!15}\rule[-0.6 cm]{17.2 cm}{0.03 cm}}

\fcolorbox{white}{v1}{\begin{minipage}{17 cm}
\textsc{Bac}\end{minipage}}

{\color{gray!15}\rule[0.6 cm]{17.2 cm}{0.03 cm}}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are some conflicts between `wasysym` and `mathabx`; both define symbols with the same name, including `\leftmoon` and `\rightmoon`. The simplest thing would be to remove one of the packages, unless you really need both. In that case, you can delete the offending commands in between loading the packages.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\let\leftmoon\relax
\let\rightmoon\relax
\let\fullmoon\relax
\let\newmoon\relax
\let\diameter\relax
\usepackage{mathabx}
\begin{document}
abc
\end{document}
```